# How to change the host in AngularJS (using PhoneGap in iOS)

Tags: cordova, angularjs

I'm new in mobile web app development. Phonegap visits my native index.html. That url will be "file://localhost/Users/.../www/index.html". So the $location in AngularJS can not give a right host, when I use $routeProvider. I need a host start in www folder. How to fix it with Angular or Phonegap?

Comment: I found that ios could make custom URL,but when I launched my app The window,location.href also gave me a "file:///......".What can I do next?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. What actually is your goal, as I do not clearly understand the question. Please elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to bake in the URL that your $http requestes will hit, rather than trying to infer from $location.